# How to make picturebox change image smooth and fast

Tags: c#, image, hover, picturebox

I got a picture box that got an original image in my program. When i hover with my mouse over it it changes picture to another picture and when i leave it changes back.
But..
There is such a delay to change to the right picture if i hover over it or not. It takes like 1 second before it changes, What should i change to improve the speed of the change? This is the code i am using at the moment:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = ABC_Bok.Properties.Resources.BokVänsterhörn_1;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = ABC_Bok.Properties.Resources.BokVänsterhörnet;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the third time today that I've seen this issue.  `MouseHover` is raised when the mouse pointer STOPS OVER a control.  If you want something to happen as soon as the mouse pointer goes over the control then you want `MouseEnter`, just as you're using `MouseLeave` for the change back again.

Comment: Wow sorry man..You don't have to rage about it. How many things has not been answered multiple times in this world? Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I wasn't raging about anything.  I was merely commenting that I'd seen the same issue three times in the same day.  Mind you,. it does mean that three people on the same day didn't read the documentation for the `MouseHover` event.